# Hosting the build from shadow-cjls

Tags: clojurescript, shadow-cljs

How do i host the  browser build?

I do not get it, i run:
npx shadow-cljs release app

[image]

npm start?
node app.js is wrong
I cannot launch app.js in the browser. What am i doing wrong?

My shadow-cljs.edn looks like this:

```
{:source-paths ["src"]
 :dependencies [[binaryage/devtools "1.0.6"]
                [nrepl "0.9.0"]
                [reagent "1.1.1"]]
 :builds       {:app {:target     :browser
                      :output-dir "public/js"
                      :asset-path "/js"
                      :modules    {:app {:entries [simpletodo.core]}}
                      :devtools   {:after-load simpletodo.core/mount-root}}}

 :dev-http     {3000 {:root    "public"
                      :handler user/app}}}
```

One level higher, i would think the index.html could be the right one, but it looks like this.

[image]

I even put in this HTML file and started the HTML, but it would not work. All i get is a white page:

[image]
➜  simpletodo cat index.html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
    <title>Browser Starter</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>shadow-cljs - Browser</h1>
<div id="app"></div>
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
<script src="/public/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the second screenshot it tells you to run `npx shadow-cljs watch app`. On the console it will tell you that a web server will be ready on port 8080, so you can open your app on `http://localhost:8080`. Feel free to look on this example project: https://github.com/dfuenzalida/fabric-todos

Comment: @DenisFuenzalida Ah okay, that mean i build with :browser for the internal shadow-cljs webserver?

Answer (score 3):

Can you clarify what you mean by "hosting the build"?

If you are just testing stuff you can run `npx shadow-cljs server` (and keep it running) which will also run the `:dev-http` servers in the build config. So your files would be accessible via http://localhost:3000, just like they would be with a running `watch`.

A `release` build produces an optimized `.js` file. `shadow-cljs` is not used in production environments and is out of the picture after producing the files.

Any webserver capable of serving static files will work at that point. Common options include nginx, apache or just a CLJ webserver (eg. jetty).